# How to merge two dictionaries in C# with duplicates

Tags: c#-3.0, dictionary, merge

Is there a way in C# to merge two dictionaries? I have two dictionaries that may has the same keys, but I am looking for a way to merge them so, in the end there is a dictionary with one key and the values from both the dictionaries merged.
I found the following code but it does not handle duplicates.

```
Dictionary Mydictionary<string, string[]> = new Dictionary<string, string[]>();
Mydictonary.Union(secondDictionary).ToDictionary( pair => pair.Key, pair => pair.Value);
```

Comment: Could you define what you mean by "merged" in the context of a single key with multiple merged values?

Comment: Hi Jeffrey,
For example,
My first dictionary is {"Key One" => "Value 1", Value 2"}
My second dictionary is {"key One" => "Value 3"}

The merged dictionary i am looking for is
{"Key One" => "Value1", "Value2", "Value3"}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a LINQ approach, try this:

```
Dictionary<string, string[]> firstDic = new Dictionary<string, string[]>  
{  
    {"apple", new [] {"red"}},  
    {"orange", new [] {"orange"}}  
};

Dictionary<string, string[]> secondDic = new Dictionary<string, string[]>
{
    {"apple", new [] {"green"}},
    {"banana", new [] {"yellow"}}
};

Dictionary<string, string[]> resultDic = firstDic.Union(secondDic)
    .GroupBy(o => o.Key)
    .ToDictionary(o => o.Key, o => o.SelectMany(kvp => kvp.Value).ToArray());
```

For the sample data, you'll get a Dictionary with 3 KeyValuePairs, and the item with a Key of "apple" will have an Array with "red" and "green" for the value.

Comment: +1 I love your examples. I am surprised that the default equality comparer for `KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>` is not based on `TKey`. I didn't expect the `firstDic.Union(secondDic)` to retain dups. Interesting.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```
foreach (var value in secondDictionary)
    if (myDictionary.Contains(value.Key))
        myDictionary[value.Key] = myDictionary[value.Key]
                                     .Concat(value.Value).ToArray();
    else
        myDictionary[value.Key] = value.Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
Dictionary<string, string[]> dict1 = new Dictionary<string, string[]>();
Dictionary<string, string[]> dict2 = new Dictionary<string, string[]>();

Dictionary<string, List<string>> combined = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

foreach (var pair in dict1) combined.Add(pair.Key, new List<string>(pair.Value));
foreach (var pair in dict2)
{
    List<string> list;

    if (!combined.TryGetValue(pair.Key, out list)) combined.Add(pair.Key, list = new List<string>());

    list.AddRange(pair.Value);
}
```

If you *really* want the result as a `Dictionary<string, string[]>`, you can tack this on to the end:

```
Dictionary<string, string[]> combinedArray = new Dictionary<string, string[]>();

foreach (var pair in combined) combinedArray.Add(pair.Key, pair.Value.ToArray());
```