# Concat two dictionary with same key records

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I want to merge two dictionaries. When I try this I get an error about duplicate keys. How can I merge two dictionaries which have the same keys?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Dictionary<Class1.Deneme, List<string>> dict1 = new Dictionary<Class1.Deneme, List<string>>();
        Dictionary<Class1.Deneme, List<string>> dict2 = new Dictionary<Class1.Deneme, List<string>>();
        Dictionary<Class1.Deneme, List<string>> dict3 = new Dictionary<Class1.Deneme, List<string>>();

        List<string> list1 = new List<string>() { "a", "b" };
        List<string> list2 = new List<string>() { "c", "d" };
        List<string> list3 = new List<string>() { "e", "f" };
        List<string> list4 = new List<string>() { "g", "h" };

        dict1.Add(Class1.Deneme.Buyer, list1);
        dict2.Add(Class1.Deneme.Buyer, list2);
        dict3 = dict1.Concat(dict2).ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value);

        Console.Read();
    }
}

public class Class1
{
    public enum Deneme
    { 
        Customer=1, 
        Buyer=2,
        Supplier=3
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2669610/how-to-merge-two-didctionaries-in-c-sharp-with-duplicates

Comment: What is `Class1.Deneme`?

Comment: What do you want to do with two items with the same key? Take the first? Take the second? Log an error and ignore it? Something else?

Comment: i have a two dictionary which they come from different function i want to merge them one dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how about

```
static IDictionary<TKey, TValue> Merge<TKey, TValue>(
    this IDictionary<TKey, TValue> left,
    IDictionary<TKey, TValue> right,
    Func<TKey, TValue, TValue, TValue> valueMerger)
{
    var result = new Dictionary<TKey, TValue>();
    foreach(var pair in left.Concat(right))
    {
        if (result.ContainsKey(pair.Key))
        {
            result[pair.Key] = valueMerger(
                                   pair.Key,
                                   pair.Value,
                                   result[pair.Key]);
            continue;
        }

        result.Add(pair.Key, pair.Value);
    }

    return result;
}
```

so, you'd need to supply a delegate to handle the case where keys are duplicated. Using your example I'd suggest,

```
var dictionary1 = new Dictionary<Class1.Deneme, List<string>>();
var dictionary2 = new Dictionary<Class1.Deneme, List<string>>();

var merged = dictionary1.Merge(
                 dictionary2,
                 (key, left, right) => left.Concat(right));
```

or perhaps you'd rather throw an exception?

```
   var merged = dictionary1.Merge(
                 dictionary2,
                 (key, left, right) => throw new ArgumentException("right", ...);
```

Comment: how can i use can you give me an example ?

Comment: @user990513, I believe I have.

Comment: This is great, thanks.  I think you can save a lookup during merges by using TryGetValue so you can pass it directly to the valueMerger Func.

Answer (score 5):

Group all KeyValuePairs by key. Then convert these groups to dictionary by selecting group key as key and flattened values as value (you can also apply `Distinct()` before `ToList()` if you do not want duplicated strings):

```
dict1.Concat(dict2)
     .GroupBy(kvp => kvp.Key) // thus no duplicated keys will be added
     .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.SelectMany(kvp => kvp.Value).ToList());
```