# C# Merge two dictionaries of integers and adding duplicates

Tags: c#

I have a problem similar to the following post:

> [How to merge two didctionaries in C# with duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2669610/how-to-merge-two-didctionaries-in-c-sharp-with-duplicates)

However, in the post, the solution concatenates duplicate strings.  I want to do something similar, but with integers, and I don't want to concatenate them, I want to add them.

So I want this:

```
var firstDic = new Dictionary<string, int>  
{  
    {"apple", 1},  
    {"orange", 2}  
};

var secondDic = new Dictionary<string, int>
{
    {"apple", 3},
    {"banana", 4}
};
```

To be unioned in some way to become:

```
var thirdDic = new Dictionary<string, int>
    {
        {"apple", 4},  //values from the two "apple" keys added together.
        {"orange", 2},  
        {"banana", 4}
    };
```

Is there any quick and easy way to do this without having to do some cumbersome nested loop mess?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use `Sum`:

```
var thirdDic = firstDic.Concat(secondDic)
    .GroupBy(o => o.Key)
    .ToDictionary(o => o.Key, o => o.Sum(v => v.Value));
```

Comment: You could include an IEqualityComparer that always returns false.  Or you could use Concat instead of Union